# JSF f:view beforePhase firing multiple times as I LEAVE the page

Tags: java, jsf

Still trying to get my problems with page loaders firing like crazy in JSF>

From this link: http://www.javabeat.net/tips/122-jsf-best-practices.html

It appears that if I put a  that it will fire once when entering the page.

However, it fires like 4 times when LEAVING the page, kind of defeats the point.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It "fires" whenever the phase changes. You can make your code in the phase listener be triggered only on certain phases, by adding a condition comparing `event.getPhaseId()` with `PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I finally tripped over that.  It's been a long day.

Comment: More recommended, let the implemented `getPhaseId()` method return `PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW`. This way the `beforePhase()` and `afterPhase()` will only be executed during the particular phase.

Comment: @BalusC - that was my initial version of the answer, but then I saw he refers to `<f:view beforePhase="#{methodBinding}>`

Comment: Oh, I didn't think a sec! Yes, checking the `PhaseId` in the method is then indeed the way to go.