# Default Sort of tr:table?

Tags: jsf, default, trinidad

Is there a way to sort the initial data displayed on UI using `tr:table`? I know there are sort properties which can be defined on `tr:column` and which are used to sort the data present in the table.

But the requirement here is to have the data sorted by default when the page is opened. Is there a way to do that except sorting the table data from back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a table by default, but you have to do it programmatically. With a little bit of work you can write a reusable [`PhaseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) which you can control from your JSF page.

Make sure it only [handles a single phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678207/jsf-fview-beforephase-firing-multiple-times-as-i-leave-the-page) (for example `PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW`) and use it to set the sort order using [`setSortCriteria`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/component/UIXTable.html#setSortCriteria(java.util.List)):

```
List<SortCriterion> sortCriteria = new ArrayList<SortCriterion>(1);
String property = "myProperty";
boolean ascending = true;
sortCriteria.add(new SortCriterion(property, ascending));
myCoreTable.setSortCriteria(sortCriteria);
```

Now you only have to add two `<f:attribute/>`s on your table to pass both the property name and the ascending boolean so you can create a reusable listener for all your tables.

In your `<tr:document>` you can have a `<f:attribute/>` with a list of table ID's to process.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know: No!

You can read from here for more information:
["TRINIDAD-1491"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-1491)